# ¿Cómo hacer una llamada a una función que contiene variables de registro? C++

Tags: c++, array, estructuras-de-datos

Resulta que a una función le tengo que pasar varios parámetros:

Código:

```
const int MAX = 6;
typedef int TipoMatriz[MAX][MAX];
struct TipoZona{
    int ancho;
    int alto;
};
```

En el siguiente módulo:

```
bool esPosibleRellenarZona (TipoZona zona, int fila, int columna, TipoMatriz M);
```

... no sé pasarle muy bien lo de `TipoZona zona` y `TipoMatriz M` para que lo calcule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*TipoZona* y *TipoMatriz* son **Objetos** asi que debes tener un clase que se llame *TipoZona* y otra clase que se llame *TipoMatriz* y ya de ahí los obtienes, te dejo como es la creación de una clase en c++, y cabe destacar que sus atributos son privados:

```
//Esto define la clase TipoMatriz
class TipoMatriz{
};
```